# How does pip resolve entries in install_requires especially in regards to already installed packages from conda?

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

In my project I have a dependency on a python package that is only available via conda and not pip. I'm aware that pip can not find it and hence cannot install it if it is not already installed. But I still wanted to add it to `install_requires` so at least the install fails and the users knows what is missing.

In fact I tried that and for this specific dependency pip always says it's not installed even if the correct version is in fact installed. I also depend on numpy which happens to be already installed by conda as well and that one is found by pip (+ same for additional dependencies)

So I'm a bit confused on how the resolution works, how pip determines a package is installed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `pip` checks if a `egg-info` or `dist-info` folder for the mentioned package exists and what version the folder name is. Example: `numpy-1.19.2.dist-info`
For `dist-info` the simple presence of the folder is not enough. It must also contain a METADATA file. However it can be empty.

Anyway the conclusion is that if a package does not create one of these folders upon installation, `pip` doesn't see it's installed and hence will fail due to a missing requirement.